# Watcher action to message Teams channel fails due to bad payload

Tags: webhooks, elk, elasticsearch-watcher

I created an ELK Watcher with this action in my `Watch JSON` to send a message to a Teams channel:

```
"msteams_webhook": {
  "webhook": {
    "scheme": "https",
    "host": "my.host.com",
    "port": 443,
    "method": "post",
    "path": "/webhookb2/path",
    "params": {},
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
      "text": "Found the following 4XX or 5XX errors in logs"
    }    
  }
}
```

When I execute it I get a 400 error with this message in the response body:

> Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook.

I think the issue is with the structure of my `JSON` body but I'm not sure. Can anybody spot the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
"msteams_webhook": {
  "throttle_period_in_millis": 60000,
  "webhook": {
    "scheme": "https",
    "host": "my.host.com",
    "port": 443,
    "method": "post",
    "path": "/webhookb2/path",
    "params": {},
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": """{
        "type":"message",
        "attachments":[
          {
            "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "contentUrl":null,
            "content":{
              "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
              "type":"AdaptiveCard",
              "version":"1.2",
              "body":[
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Found the following 4XX or 5XX errors in logs"
                }                                
              ],
              "msteams": {
                "width": "Full"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }"""
  }
}
```